# Non-constructive comments and downvotes

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For some time I'm receiving very odd, sometimes personal-related comments and downvotes to my answers from one specific user canonizing ironize. I don't know the person, and I think I may be not the only one facing such a situations not only with that particular user. Maybe we can do something or make an instrument to flag this kind of counter-productive behaviours? The links are here:

- [Does TOR Leak Time and Time Zone?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/does-tor-leak-time-and-time-zone/13452?noredirect=1#comment14436_13452)
- [Why does Tor only work on TCP?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13389/why-does-tor-only-work-on-tcp/13398?noredirect=1#comment14343_13398)
- [Is Tor over wifi safe? Can people who snoop on my traffic de-anonymize my Tor traffic?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13408/is-tor-over-wifi-safe-can-people-who-snoop-on-my-traffic-de-anonymize-my-tor-tr/13410?noredirect=1#comment14377_13410)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversation has gotten heated and a bit personal a few times indeed. I've been away over the holidays but I'll keep an eye on it and take direct action if necessary.

Comment: happy holidays, man! It has actually continued in other posts - IMHO it's just a kid self-stating issue

Comment: sadly, it's continued... do you need urls? I've flagged this "activity" with flags, if you need urls - just tell me. This person either needs a skill-up or a shrink, I think