# Personal offending messages

Tags: support, moderators, abuse

It started with [this](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315/non-constructive-comments-and-downvotes), now I see the direct offense [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13498/should-i-change-the-timezone-of-my-laptop-to-utc/13499?noredirect=1#comment14504_13499). Yes, I do remember the "flame threads" back to 1999, and - no, I don't consider it to be a sane way of making a dialogs. Note to moderators: I will respond to this paricular answer and  all the next counter-constructive ones in the very way set by this person first. Please - either reason this person or I will not be responsible for ALL the foul language used. Insult is not the way dialogues are done, but silence is not the way of withstanding them either. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented on your other post:

> The conversation has gotten heated and a bit personal a few times indeed. I've been away over the holidays but I'll keep an eye on it and take direct action if necessary.

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15852/can-i-use-hiddenservice-address-for-irc-and-ssh-or-just-one/15853 - here it goes again, I think the moderator intervention should be in order here